# Update a parent theme JQuery property in the child theme

Tags: jquery, child-theme

A sticky content and sidebar is implemented in the parent theme. It gets called in the parent theme js file via:

```
if ( ( typeof jQuery.fn.theiaStickySidebar !== 'undefined' ) && ( typeof ResizeSensor !== 'undefined' ) ) {
    jQuery('#primary, #secondary').theiaStickySidebar({
    additionalMarginTop: 40
    });
}
```

in the child theme I would now need to modify the jQuery property additionalMarginTop and set it to a different value.

How would I call jQuery to set a different additionalMarginTop?

The child theme already got it's custom js file enqueued. I know that I can dequeue the parent theme custom js file and do all the parent theme jquery calls in my child theme js file instead.

But I'm looking for a better way, like just updating the jQuery objects property.

Any hints are welcome ;)

thanks & greetings
Becki

Comment: Why don't you add margin top using CSS code instead of javascript?

Comment: Where this code is placed ? In a particular script or inline ?

Comment: The parent theme doesn't sound very well coded. If it were me, I'd pick a different parent or custom code something. Adding margin via jQuery is not the recommended method and removing it through jQuery will be difficult to achieve.

Comment: The sticky sidebar script in question is here [Theia Sticky Sidebar](https://github.com/WeCodePixels/theia-sticky-sidebar).

The code is placed in the parent themes custom js file. You can preview here at the current in dev [website] (http://update123.beckspaced.com/technologien/)

Here's the [parent theme custom js] (http://update123.beckspaced.com/wp-content/themes/spacious-pro/js/spacious-custom.min.js?ver=4.7.5)

here's the [child theme custom js] (view-source:http://update123.beckspaced.com/wp-content/themes/beckspaced-com/js/functions.js?ver=4.7.5)

Comment: I don't think the parent theme is badly coded. It's common to specify properties in jQuery functions when init the jQuery object.

There must be a way to update the jQuery object property via another jQuery call, e.g.

    jQuery('#primary, #secondary').theiaStickySidebar.additionalMarginTop = 400;

Anyone be able to help?